# Columns and rows in a 2D array?

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array

```
        {
        int woodchuckSim = 0;
        int numOfDays = 0;
        bool validNumber = false;
        bool validDays = false;
        Random ran1 = new Random();
        
        //display banner

        //Ask user how many woodchucks to simulate
        while(!validNumber)
        {
            Write("How many woodchucks would you like to simulate? (1 - 100) ");
            int.TryParse(ReadLine(), out woodchuckSim);
            if((woodchuckSim <= 0) || (woodchuckSim > 100))
            {
                WriteLine("\nPlease enter a correct amount of woodchucks to simulate: ");
            }
            else
            {
                validNumber = true;
            }
        }

        //Ask user how many days to simulate
        while(!validDays)
        {
            Write("\nHow many days would you like to simulate? (1 - 10) ");
            int.TryParse(ReadLine(), out numOfDays);
            if((numOfDays <= 0) || (numOfDays > 10))
            {
                WriteLine("Please enter a positive whole number between 1 and 10: ");
            }
            else
            {
                validDays = true;
            }
        }

        //Using random class populate each cell between 1 and 50 that represents # of pieces of wood chucked by specific woodchuck on that specific day
        int[,] sim = new int[woodchuckSim, numOfDays];

        WriteLine($"{woodchuckSim} {numOfDays}");
        for (int i = 0; i < sim.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < sim.GetLength(1); j++)
            {
                sim[i, j] = ran1.Next(1, 50);
                Write(sim[i, j] + "\t");
            }
            {
                WriteLine(i.ToString());
            }
        }
        WriteLine("Press any key to continue...");
        ReadLine();
    }
```

This is my code so far in my woodchuck simulation coding assignment but I need a columns and rows label on the side and top like the picture. I really don't have any idea how to do this, and I'm not sure if I'm missing a code or typed something wrong. Also at the end of the code it prints out the number of woodchucks simulated in a straight line like if the user typed in 15 it would print 0-14 in a straight line at the end which is not something I want, any help will be appreciated, thanks! (The second picture is what my code is printing)

[image]

[image: WhatMyCodeIsPrinting]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few steps to do this, but it's not too hard:

1. Write the column headers (include blank space at the beginning where the row headers go
2. Write the column underlines
3. For each row, write the row header first
4. Then for each column in the row, write the column data
5. After the column data is written, write a newline to start the next row

Here's a sample that produces a table similar to your output. Note that we use `PadLeft` to pad each column data with spaces so they're all the same width. I've also included `Sum` and `Avg` columns based on your comment below. Additionally, to clean up the main code, I added methods to write text in a different color and a method to get an integer from the user:

```
private static readonly Random Random = new Random();

private static void WriteColor(string text,
    ConsoleColor foreColor = ConsoleColor.Gray,
    ConsoleColor backColor = ConsoleColor.Black)
{
    Console.ForegroundColor = foreColor;
    Console.BackgroundColor = backColor;
    Console.Write(text);
    Console.ResetColor();
}

private static void WriteLineColor(string text,
    ConsoleColor foreColor = ConsoleColor.Gray,
    ConsoleColor backColor = ConsoleColor.Black)
{
    WriteColor(text + Environment.NewLine, foreColor, backColor);
}

public static int GetIntFromUser(string prompt, Func<int, bool> validator = null)
{
    var isValid = true;
    int result;

    do
    {
        if (!isValid)
        {
            WriteLineColor("Invalid input, please try again.", ConsoleColor.Red);
        }
        else isValid = false;

        Console.Write(prompt);
    } while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out result) ||
                (validator != null && !validator.Invoke(result)));

    return result;
}

public static void Main()
{
    int columnWidth = 6;

    ConsoleColor sumForeColor = ConsoleColor.DarkRed;
    ConsoleColor sumBackColor = ConsoleColor.Gray;
    ConsoleColor avgForeColor = ConsoleColor.White;
    ConsoleColor avgBackColor = ConsoleColor.DarkGreen;

    int numWoodchucks = GetIntFromUser(
        "How many woodchucks would you like to simulate? (1 - 100) ... ",
        x => x >= 1 && x <= 100);
    int numDays = GetIntFromUser(
        "How many days would you like to simulate? (1 - 10) .......... ",
        x => x >= 1 && x <= 10);
    int[,] data = new int[numWoodchucks, numDays];

    // Write column headers, starting with a blank row header
    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.Write(new string(' ', columnWidth));
    for (int col = 1; col <= data.GetLength(1); col++)
    {
        Console.Write($"{col}".PadLeft(columnWidth));
    }
    Console.Write(" ");
    WriteColor("Sum".PadLeft(columnWidth - 1), sumForeColor, sumBackColor);
    Console.Write(" ");
    WriteLineColor("Avg".PadLeft(columnWidth - 1), avgForeColor, avgBackColor);

    // Write column header underlines
    Console.Write(new string(' ', columnWidth));
    for (int col = 0; col < data.GetLength(1); col++)
    {
        Console.Write(" _____");
    }
    Console.Write(" ");
    WriteColor("_____", sumForeColor, sumBackColor);
    Console.Write(" ");
    WriteLineColor("_____", avgForeColor, avgBackColor);

    int total = 0;

    for (int row = 0; row < data.GetLength(0); row++)
    {
        // Write row header
        Console.Write($"{row + 1} |".PadLeft(columnWidth));

        int rowSum = 0;

        // Store and write row data
        for (int col = 0; col < data.GetLength(1); col++)
        {
            data[row, col] = Random.Next(1, 50);
            Console.Write($"{data[row, col]}".PadLeft(columnWidth));
            rowSum += data[row, col];
        }

        // Write sum and average
        Console.Write(" ");
        WriteColor($"{rowSum}".PadLeft(columnWidth - 1),
            sumForeColor, sumBackColor);
        Console.Write(" ");
        WriteLineColor($"{Math.Round((double) rowSum / data.GetLength(1), 1):F1}"
            .PadLeft(columnWidth - 1), avgForeColor, avgBackColor);

        total += rowSum;
    }

    // Write the sum of all the items
    Console.Write(new string(' ', columnWidth + columnWidth * data.GetLength(1) + 1));
    WriteColor("_____", sumForeColor, sumBackColor);
    Console.Write(" ");
    WriteLineColor("_____", avgForeColor, avgBackColor);

    // Write the average of all the items
    Console.Write(new string(' ', columnWidth + columnWidth * data.GetLength(1) + 1));
    WriteColor($"{total}".PadLeft(columnWidth - 1), sumForeColor, sumBackColor);
    Console.Write(" ");
    WriteLineColor(
        $"{Math.Round((double) total / (data.GetLength(0) * data.GetLength(1)), 1):F1}"
        .PadLeft(columnWidth - 1), avgForeColor, avgBackColor);

    Console.Write("\nPress any key to continue...");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: You are amazing, thank you so much! Do you happen to know how to add up all of the random numbers and get the average of the number of woodchucks?

Comment: I updated the sample with `Sum` and `Avg` columns to demonstrate

Answer (score 0):

Not tested, but something like this:

```
    Write("\t");
    for (int i = 0; i < sim.GetLength(0); i++)
    {
        Write(i.ToString() + "\t");
    }
    WriteLine("\t");
    for (int i = 0; i < sim.GetLength(0); i++)
    {
        Write("_____\t");
    }
    WriteLine();

   for (int i = 0; i < sim.GetLength(0); i++)
    {
        {
            WriteLine(i.ToString().PadLeft(3) + " |\t");
        }            
        for (int j = 0; j < sim.GetLength(1); j++)
        {
            sim[i, j] = ran1.Next(1, 50);
            Write(sim[i, j] + "\t");
        }
    }
```

Like I said, not tested, just typed right into the editor here, but that should get you close. Also, look at the string.PadLeft(int) function to get your numbers to be right-justified like the example.